# Keeping a loose touch with someone / a group of people

Tags: phrase-request

Imagine after a long time two retired colleagues meet each other and start to talk about the past and memories; suddenly one of them asks the other one: "do you have any information about the company (where they used to work together)?" and the other one wants to answer, "yes, I **somehow** communicate with them" meaning that I have kept not a very close touch with them, but once in a while (e.g. every 6 months or once in a year) I go there and meet some remained colleagues who are working there yet.

- The expression "lose touch" makes sense here, but what I need is that 
  how a native would say what 'B' says (self-made sentences) here in the most natural way:

> -**A**- Do you have any news from the company?
>
> -**B**- Yes, I’m keeping a **loose touch** with the company

Comment: *decide yourself* - lose or loose? :)

Comment: @MaulikV I guess it should be 'loose', because 'lose' a simple form of the verb, while 'loose' is an adjective. ;)

Comment: @A-friend, we might keep **in loose touch** (or **loosely in touch**) but we woul  _never_ **keep a loose touch.** No English speaker would ever say that.

Answer (score 2):

Your original phrase

> loose touch

could be used and would be understood to be "loosely in touch".

A possible other phrase might be

> from time to time
>
> We've been in touch from time to time.
>   *We communicate periodically but irregularly*

Comment: Thank you very much Peter. It was a really helpful post. Thank you again. :)